# How to calculate the covariance of a stochastic integral and a Riemann integral?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Right now, I want to figure out the covariance of a stochastic integral and a Riemann integral in the following form:

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\int_{0}^{t}\exp[B(t)-B(s)]ds \cdot \int_{0}^{t}\exp[B(t)-B(s)]dW(s)\right)\,,$$
where $B(\cdot)$ and $W(\cdot)$ are independent Brownian motions, or $d\langle B, W \rangle_t = \gamma dt$.

My guess to this is $0$ and my calculation is:

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\int_{0}^{t}\exp[B(t)-B(s)]ds \cdot \int_{0}^{t}\exp[B(t)-B(s)]dW(s)\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(\int_{0}^{t}\exp[B(t)-B(s)]\int_{0}^{t}\exp[B(t)-B(r)]dr dW(s)\right) = 0 \,,$$
by virtue of $\mathbb{E}(\int \cdot\ dW) = 0$.

Am I correct? If not, what tool can I use to derive the correct result?

Comment: I woulds guess Ito's lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4's_lemma